# Include latest author posts with pagination in single template?

Tags: wp-query, pagination, single

I've inserted a `WP_Query` in my single.php template to show the last 12 posts of an author. Everything works ok, the 12 posts are being shown.

Now, I want to have it paginated. So the user can see more than 12 posts.

Here is my `WP_Query` and pagination code:

```
<?php 
                $paged = get_query_var( 'paged' ) ? get_query_var( 'paged' ) : 1; 
                $args = array(
                'author'=> get_the_author_meta( 'ID' ),
                  'posts_per_page' => 12,
                  'paged'          => $paged,
                  'order'    => 'DESC', 
                    'post_type' => 'post',

                );
                $query1 = new WP_Query( $args );

                // The Loop
                 while ( $query1->have_posts() ) : $query1->the_post(); 
                     get_template_part( 'content', get_post_format() );
                 endwhile;  

?>


<nav id="nav-below-infinite" class="navigation" role="navigation">
            <h3 class="assistive-text"><?php _e( 'Post navigation', 'twentytwelve' ); ?></h3>
            <div class="nav-previous alignleft"><?php next_posts_link( __( '<span class="meta-nav">&larr;</span> Older posts', 'twentytwelve' ), $query1->max_num_pages ); ?></div>
            <div class="nav-next alignright"><?php previous_posts_link( __( 'Newer posts <span class="meta-nav">&rarr;</span>', 'twentytwelve' ) ); ?></div>
</nav><!-- #nav-below .navigation -->

<?php wp_reset_postdata(); ?>
```

Nothing is shown for page 2.

Comment: So it shows 12 posts on the first page and nothing on the second?

Comment: @unifiedac yes, there is no link for the second page.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found this to be simpler and more efective to implement than Brad's answer:

I came up with the following code as I just needed the next and previous page links. Plus, it compliments with my code above. I also needed to custom style it so I avoided using the `paginate_links()` function because it didnt let me style it the way I needed it.

```
$author = get_user_by('id',get_the_author_meta( 'ID' ));
$total_pages = $query1->max_num_pages;
if ($total_pages > 1) {
    $format = array();
    //HERE WE SET THE BASE FOR OUR PAGE LINKS,
    //IN THIS CASE, WE NEED THE AUTHOR'S URL PAGE
    $base = esc_url(home_url( '/' . $author->user_nicename . '/' ));
    $prev_text = __( 'Previous Page', 'mylangfile' ); // Supply translatable string
    $next_text = __( 'Next Page', 'mylangfile' ); // Supply translatable string
    $current_page = max( 1, get_query_var('paged') );
         $prev_page = $current_page-1;
         $next_page = $current_page+1;
     if( get_option('permalink_structure') ) {
         $format['current_page'] = $base.'page/'.$current_page.'/';
         $format['prev_page'] = $base.'page/'.$prev_page.'/';
         $format['next_page'] = $base.'page/'.$next_page.'/';
     } else {
         //IN CASE YOU ARE NOT USING PRETTYLINKS
     }

echo '<nav id="nav-below-infinite" class="navigation" role="navigation">';
  if($paged > 1) {
     echo '<div class="nav-next alignleft">';
     echo '<a href="'.$format['prev_page'].'"><span class="meta-nav">←</span>'.$prev_text.'</a>'; 
     echo '</div>';
  }
  echo '<div class="nav-previous alignleft">';
  echo '<a href="'.$format['next_page'].'"><span class="meta-nav">←</span>'.$next_text.'</a>';
  echo '</div>';
echo '</nav>';
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Another option would be to use the Twenty Fourteen themes author.php file with the template tag that theme includes for the paging nav.

Then you can use [`pre_get_posts`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Action_Reference/pre_get_posts) to alter the query from your functions file.

**You want page navigation for the author archives rather than single post navigation which is what you posted in your question.**

You'll find this code in a file named template-tags.php in the includes folder of the theme.

```
if ( ! function_exists( 'twentyfourteen_paging_nav' ) ) :

function twentyfourteen_paging_nav() {

if ( $GLOBALS['wp_query']->max_num_pages < 2 ) {
    return;
}

$paged        = get_query_var( 'paged' ) ? intval( get_query_var( 'paged' ) ) : 1;
$pagenum_link = html_entity_decode( get_pagenum_link() );
$query_args   = array();
$url_parts    = explode( '?', $pagenum_link );

if ( isset( $url_parts[1] ) ) {
    wp_parse_str( $url_parts[1], $query_args );
}

$pagenum_link = remove_query_arg( array_keys( $query_args ), $pagenum_link );
$pagenum_link = trailingslashit( $pagenum_link ) . '%_%';

$format  = $GLOBALS['wp_rewrite']->using_index_permalinks() && ! strpos( $pagenum_link, 'index.php' ) ? 'index.php/' : '';
$format .= $GLOBALS['wp_rewrite']->using_permalinks() ? user_trailingslashit( 'page/%#%', 'paged' ) : '?paged=%#%';

// Set up paginated links.
$links = paginate_links( array(
    'base'     => $pagenum_link,
    'format'   => $format,
    'total'    => $GLOBALS['wp_query']->max_num_pages,
    'current'  => $paged,
    'mid_size' => 1,
    'add_args' => array_map( 'urlencode', $query_args ),
    'prev_text' => __( '&larr; Previous', 'twentyfourteen' ),
    'next_text' => __( 'Next &rarr;', 'twentyfourteen' ),
) );

if ( $links ) :

?>
<nav class="navigation paging-navigation" role="navigation">
    <h1 class="screen-reader-text"><?php _e( 'Posts navigation', 'twentyfourteen' ); ?></h1>
    <div class="pagination loop-pagination">
        <?php echo $links; ?>
    </div><!-- .pagination -->
</nav><!-- .navigation -->
<?php
endif;
}
endif;
```

**Code Installation**

You can copy over the template-tags.php file to your theme and remove all the code excluding the above code then copy over the author.php file as well.

Then simply include the file from your functions file.

```
require get_template_directory() . '/template-tags.php';
```

I ripped this code out recently and tested it on other themes and its a great solution which you can easily modify to work on any theme for archive page navigation simply by using the template tag in a custom function or directly in a template file.

Comment: Had the exact same thing in mind, hahaha. +1

Comment: Hi Brad, thanks for your suggestion; however, I came up with a simpler solution that better suits my needs. Besides, I could not figure out how to apply a custom style to the `paginate_links` function output. If there is any improvement you can give to my solution, it is very welcome.

Comment: Could you please link to the result on your site so i can take a look thanks.

Comment: Sure! Is there a way to give you the link privately?

Comment: Brad, I just sent you the link to one of your emails I found on your google account.